# Unable to access Yocto Poky

Tags: git, yocto, handshake

I am trying to do a `repo sync` to make a new Yocto build.  I set it up using

> `curl http://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo`

and

> `repo init -u http://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-zeus -m imx-5.4.3-2.0.0.xml` .

When I run a `repo sync` I get the following

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

I have run my curl `sudo update-ca-certificates` to no avail.

I am using Ubuntu 14, since I already failed miserably trying to make a Yocto build with Ubuntu 20.  Funnily enough, it did sync correctly on Ubuntu 20, just wouldn't build.